# Не удалось создать таблицу: (1364) Field 'name' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, веб-программирование

пытаюсь сохранить значение, но выдает ошибку:
Не удалось создать таблицу: (1364) Field 'name' doesn't have a default value

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dll");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
else {
echo "подключено";
}
if (
!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO users(adv) VALUES ($sp)")) {
echo "Не удалось создать таблицу: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Comment: Есть 2 варианта: 1) каждый раз явно указывать в запросе `INSERT INTO users(adv, name) VALUES ($sp, '')` какое значение нужно записать в поле `name`. 2) Указать значение поля `name` по умолчанию в описании таблицы `users`.

Comment: А это не подразумевает, что пользователь при регистрации сможет указать имя в виде пробела?

Comment: @Resawa БД сохраняет данные в том виде, в котором вы пропустите их. Сделайте валидацию для этого случая и показывайте пользователю ошибку при попытке создания такого профиля.

Comment: Как этот запрос `INSERT INTO users(adv, name) VALUES ($sp, '')` может подразумевать, что пользователь введет пробел, если в поле `name` явно пишется пустая строка? Это вы контролируете, что писать в базу... а не пользователь.